# How to get each data-id value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find each `data-id` and then print them out to console.

I tried the following:

```js
$('.raffle-user-entries .raffle-user-entry').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).find('raffle-user-entry-item').data('id'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="raffle-user-items">
    <div class="raffle-user-item">
        <div class="raffle-user-avatar">
            <div class="raffle-user-avatar-box">
                <a href="/steam/profile/76561198170191215" target="_blank">
                    <img src="/images/avatars/e369853df766fa44e1ed0ff613f563bd.jpg" original-title="Winner: tytyfhfh">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="raffle-user-info">
            <div class="raffle-user-info-item">
                <div class="raffle-user-info-title">ID:</div>
                <div class="raffle-user-info-value">224</div>
            </div>
            <div class="raffle-user-info-item">
                <div class="raffle-user-info-title">Ended at:</div>
                <div class="raffle-user-info-value">27.12.2016 06:32:21</div>
            </div>
            <div class="raffle-user-info-item">
                <div class="raffle-user-info-title">Winning ticket:</div>
                <div class="raffle-user-info-value"><i class="fa fa-ticket"></i> <span>4.762420565%</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="raffle-user-info-item">
                <div class="raffle-user-info-title">Secret:</div>
                <div class="raffle-user-info-value"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> <span>12a5567c4e918e293debc5ae1bd6846da8595f1345306bc2efa28c6a4a07316a</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="raffle-user-info-item">
                <div class="raffle-user-info-title">Hash:</div>
                <div class="raffle-user-info-value">814ba5c06847c1d4e78a5076c8222edf</div>
            </div>
            <div class="raffle-user-info-item">
                <div class="raffle-user-info-title">Skins:</div>
                <div class="raffle-user-info-value">19</div>
            </div>
            <div class="raffle-user-info-item">
                <div class="raffle-user-info-title">Value:</div>
                <div class="raffle-user-info-value">$1.44</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="raffle-user-entries">
            <div class="raffle-user-entries-title">Entries of winner</div>
            <div class="raffle-user-entry">
                <div class="raffle-user-entry-item">
                    <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Glove Case" target="_blank" original-title="Glove Case entered by tytyfhfh in entry #668 worth $0.48">
                        <img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/2066632015/100fx100f">
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/P250 | Valence (Field-Tested)" target="_blank" original-title="P250 | Valence (Field-Tested) entered by tytyfhfh in entry #668 worth $0.08">
                        <img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/937246119/100fx100f">
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Gamma 2 Case" target="_blank" original-title="Gamma 2 Case entered by tytyfhfh in entry #668 worth $0.05">
                        <img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1923037342/100fx100f">
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Chroma 3 Case" target="_blank" original-title="Chroma 3 Case entered by tytyfhfh in entry #668 worth $0.03">
                        <img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1690096482/100fx100f">
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Chroma 3 Case" target="_blank" original-title="Chroma 3 Case entered by tytyfhfh in entry #668 worth $0.03">
                        <img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1690096482/100fx100f">
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Chroma 3 Case" target="_blank" original-title="Chroma 3 Case entered by tytyfhfh in entry #668 worth $0.03">
                        <img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1690096482/100fx100f">
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Chroma 2 Case" target="_blank" original-title="Chroma 2 Case entered by tytyfhfh in entry #668 worth $0.03">
                        <img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/926978479/100fx100f">
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Revolver Case" target="_blank" original-title="Revolver Case entered by tytyfhfh in entry #668 worth $0.03">
                        <img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1432174707/100fx100f">
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Chroma 2 Case" target="_blank" original-title="Chroma 2 Case entered by tytyfhfh in entry #668 worth $0.03">
                        <img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/926978479/100fx100f">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="raffle-user-entries-title">Entries of others</div>
            <div class="raffle-user-entry">
                <div class="raffle-user-entry-item">
                    <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/XM1014 | Scumbria (Minimal Wear)" target="_blank" original-title="XM1014 | Scumbria (Minimal Wear) entered by TheSkiddelz in entry #669 worth $0.08">
                        <img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1309989973/100fx100f">
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/XM1014 | Scumbria (Battle-Scarred)" target="_blank" original-title="XM1014 | Scumbria (Battle-Scarred) entered by TheSkiddelz in entry #669 worth $0.08">
                        <img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1309988217/100fx100f">
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/SCAR-20 | Green Marine (Battle-Scarred)" target="_blank" original-title="SCAR-20 | Green Marine (Battle-Scarred) entered by TheSkiddelz in entry #669 worth $0.07">
                        <img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1310001548/100fx100f">
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Negev | Desert-Strike (Field-Tested)" target="_blank" original-title="Negev | Desert-Strike (Field-Tested) entered by TheSkiddelz in entry #669 worth $0.07">
                        <img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/520026696/100fx100f">
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/MAG-7 | Heaven Guard (Field-Tested)" target="_blank" original-title="MAG-7 | Heaven Guard (Field-Tested) entered by TheSkiddelz in entry #669 worth $0.07">
                        <img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/360453655/100fx100f">
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Dual Berettas | Dualing Dragons (Battle-Scarred)" target="_blank" original-title="Dual Berettas | Dualing Dragons (Battle-Scarred) entered by TheSkiddelz in entry #669 worth $0.07">
                        <img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1309989359/100fx100f">
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/XM1014 | Scumbria (Field-Tested)" target="_blank" original-title="XM1014 | Scumbria (Field-Tested) entered by TheSkiddelz in entry #669 worth $0.07">
                        <img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1309998372/100fx100f">
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Gamma 2 Case" target="_blank" original-title="Gamma 2 Case entered by TheSkiddelz in entry #669 worth $0.05">
                        <img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1923037342/100fx100f">
                    </a>
                    <a style="background: #E1F5B0;border: 1px solid #B8CE81;" href="https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Gamma 2 Case" data-id="8527530651" target="_blank" original-title="Commisioned item: Gamma 2 Case entered by TheSkiddelz in entry #669 worth $0.05">
                        <img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1923037342/100fx100f">
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/FAMAS | Cyanospatter (Minimal Wear)" target="_blank" original-title="FAMAS | Cyanospatter (Minimal Wear) entered by TheSkiddelz in entry #669 worth $0.04">
                        <img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/310780658/100fx100f">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="raffle-user-item">
        <div class="raffle-user-avatar">
            <div class="raffle-user-avatar-box">
                <a href="/steam/profile/76561198263286294" target="_blank">
                    <img src="/images/avatars/182be0c5cdcd5072bb1864cdee4d3d6e.jpg" original-title="Winner: TheSkiddelz">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="raffle-user-info">
            <div class="raffle-user-info-item">
                <div class="raffle-user-info-title">ID:</div>
                <div class="raffle-user-info-value">223</div>
            </div>
            <div class="raffle-user-info-item">
                <div class="raffle-user-info-title">Ended at:</div>
                <div class="raffle-user-info-value">27.12.2016 06:30:36</div>
            </div>
            <div class="raffle-user-info-item">
                <div class="raffle-user-info-title">Winning ticket:</div>
                <div class="raffle-user-info-value"><i class="fa fa-ticket"></i> <span>49.089895766%</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="raffle-user-info-item">
                <div class="raffle-user-info-title">Secret:</div>
                <div class="raffle-user-info-value"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> <span>c2940ca49136ceee4b2bbc83c59041057af65254e11ae285039d38b8b3b5ca04</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="raffle-user-info-item">
                <div class="raffle-user-info-title">Hash:</div>
                <div class="raffle-user-info-value">d3b184e107204cca29051e706cb68dff</div>
            </div>
            <div class="raffle-user-info-item">
                <div class="raffle-user-info-title">Skins:</div>
                <div class="raffle-user-info-value">5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="raffle-user-info-item">
                <div class="raffle-user-info-title">Value:</div>
                <div class="raffle-user-info-value">$0.29</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="raffle-user-entries">
            <div class="raffle-user-entries-title">Entries of winner</div>
            <div class="raffle-user-entry">
                <div class="raffle-user-entry-item">
                    <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/XM1014 | Scumbria (Minimal Wear)" target="_blank" original-title="XM1014 | Scumbria (Minimal Wear) entered by TheSkiddelz in entry #666 worth $0.08">
                        <img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1309989973/100fx100f">
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/XM1014 | Scumbria (Battle-Scarred)" target="_blank" original-title="XM1014 | Scumbria (Battle-Scarred) entered by TheSkiddelz in entry #666 worth $0.08">
                        <img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1309988217/100fx100f">
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/XM1014 | Scumbria (Field-Tested)" target="_blank" original-title="XM1014 | Scumbria (Field-Tested) entered by TheSkiddelz in entry #666 worth $0.07">
                        <img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1309998372/100fx100f">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="raffle-user-entries-title">Entries of others</div>
            <div class="raffle-user-entry">
                <div class="raffle-user-entry-item">
                    <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Sealed Graffiti | Eat It (Cash Green)" target="_blank" original-title="Sealed Graffiti | Eat It (Cash Green) entered by tytyfhfh in entry #667 worth $0.03">
                        <img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1989319524/100fx100f">
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Sealed Graffiti | Rage Mode (Blood Red)" target="_blank" original-title="Sealed Graffiti | Rage Mode (Blood Red) entered by tytyfhfh in entry #667 worth $0.03">
                        <img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1989285370/100fx100f">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Extended example](https://jsfiddle.net/f5w56wp3/)

Comment: When is the data stored?

Comment: in your fiddle example replace "$(this).find('h3').slideToggle('fast');" with " $(this).siblings("h3").slideToggle('fast');"

Comment: Oh I am sorry, I copied wrong fiddle link.

Comment: I edited first post for the right one

Comment: Do you want to get the Id from the html?

Comment: Yes for some items I have set data-id and I would like to get it.

Comment: Use this to access an attribute value:
console.log($(this).find('raffle-user-entry-item').attr('data-id'))

Comment: (1) You have a typo in the selector on `.find()` (forgot the period before the class name).  (2) *None* of the elements with class `raffle-user-entry-item` have a `data-id` attribute.

Comment: @David Then I have to use .child or something like that, because one of the child has it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/f5w56wp3/1/

- Jquery was not included in the fiddle
- `$(this).find('raffle-user-entry-item').data('id')` missed a dot on the selector in find and also data-id is present on anchor inside it

Corrected:

```
$('.raffle-user-entries .raffle-user-entry').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).find('.raffle-user-entry-item a').data('id'))
})
```